# Get data from multiple tables related to model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have `comments` table which has more related tables.

`comments` table:

```
id | comment
1  | This is comment 1
2  | This is comment 2
```

Each comment could have a decision with or without service with or without a grade.

`decisions` table:

```
id | decision
1  | This is decision 1
2  | This is decision 2
```

`services` table:

```
id | service
1  | This is service 1
2  | This is service 2
```

`grades` table:

```
id | grade
1  |   1
2  |   2
3  |   3
4  |   4
```

Then to combine these tables together I created 2 more tables:
`comment_decision` table:

```
id | decision_id | comment_id
1  |      1      |     1
2  |      1      |     2
```

A comment only has 1 decision.

`comment_services` table:

```
id | service_id | grade_id (nullable) | comment_id
1  |     1      |          null       |      1
2  |     2      |          2          |      1
3  |     2      |          3          |      2
```

A comment has multiple services that may or may not have `grade_id`.

I'm trying to fetch each comment with 1 decision, 0 or more services with or without grades.

`Comment` model:

```
//To get main comment data + decision
public function decision(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Decision::class, 'comment_decision', 'comment_id', 'decision_id', 'id');
}

//To get services
public function services(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class, 'comment_services', 'comment_id', 'service_id', 'id', 'id');
}
```

Both functions are working as expected and returning the required data. But for grades, it's not working fine.

`Service` model:

```
public function grade(){
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Grade::class, Service::class, 'service_id', 'id', 'id', 'grade_id');
}
```

`CommentController`:

```
public function edit(Request $request, ApplicationComment $comment){
    return view('comments.edit', compact('comment');
}
```

The result should be something like that:

```
array:4 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "comment" => "This is comment 1"
    "decision" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:4 [▼
            "decision_id" => 9
            "comment_id" => 1
            "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
        ]
    ]
    "services" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:6 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "service" => "This is service 1"
            "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
            "grades" => null
        ]
        1 => array:6 [▼
            "id" => 2
            "service" => "This is service 1"
            "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
            "grades" => array:3 [▼
                "id" => 1
                "grade" => "1"
                "laravel_through_key" => 2
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

The issue is that if I have multiple comments with the same `service_id` it would return the first row with that `service_id`.

So if I have the following data in `comment_services`:

```
id | service_id | grade_id | comment_id
1  |     1      |    null  |     1
2  |     2      |     3    |     1
3  |     3      |    null  |     1
4  |     2      |      2   |     2
```

In this case  `service_id = 2` exists 2 times the first with `grade_id = 3` and the second `grade_id = 2`. With `hasOneThrough` it will always return the first one:

```
id | service_id | grade_id | comment_id
2  |     2      |     3    |     1
```

I tried `hasManyThrough` but it returns both rows:

```
id | service_id | grade_id | comment_id
2  |     2      |     3    |     1
4  |     2      |     2    |     2
```

Answer (score 0):

I the short run, i think you can do it this way:

```
public function grade(int $comment_id){
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Grade::class, Service::class, 'service_id', 'id', 'id', 'grade_id')->where('comment_id', '=', $this->comment_id);
}
```

Since this method returning the Builder you can fetch it this way now:

```
$comment->service->each(function(Service $service){ echo $service->grade->id });
```

But for the long run, i suggest to reorganize the way how you collect and store this data. It seems to me that is build the wrong way.

Comment: How do you suggest building it? If I group `comment_decision` with `comment_services` there would be many `null` values and `decision_id` would be repeated for each service

Comment: @mmdev It is not a 2 sec answer, you just have to sit and think how this can be build more efficiently then it is right now.

Comment: I see 3 options the same as now, to combine `comment_decision ` and `comment_services ` and to split grade from `comment_services ` but this would be much headache as I can't even make it work the way it is now so adding a new relation would make it worse

Comment: @mmdev Just sit and make some ways what you can do, what will be reasonable and what not, after that you can try to ask community "is this way reasonable in this case" take a feedback, think again, after that make a decision. Because if you will build your app the crappy way, you will get more headache in the future. If it make sense to you.

Comment: @mmdev I'm just trying to explain you, that nobody will think for you here, You have a problem with some sort of the code, we can help here. But main logic is all relying on you. Look for the best practice, revert you question and see what google will show you. maybe you you will find a similar question related to a different framework but which will give you the idea on how to resolve your problem.